# Resco MobileApp Studio - crash when adding datasource

Tags: c#, windows-mobile

I'm trying to get the Resco MobileApp Studio demo working. It crashes Visual Studio when I try to add a datasource (SQL CE database file). Here's the error from the event log:

```
Version=1
EventType=CLR20r3
EventTime=129227782741643080
ReportType=1
Consent=1
UploadTime=129227782742193080
ReportIdentifier=131751b8-87ef-11df-91fd-001c7e7f92a5
Response.BucketId=1239928215
Response.BucketTable=5
Response.type=4
Sig[0].Name=Problem Signature 01
Sig[0].Value=devenv.exe
Sig[1].Name=Problem Signature 02
Sig[1].Value=9.0.30729.1
Sig[2].Name=Problem Signature 03
Sig[2].Value=488f2b50
Sig[3].Name=Problem Signature 04
Sig[3].Value=Resco.Wizard
Sig[4].Name=Problem Signature 05
Sig[4].Value=1.0.0.0
Sig[5].Name=Problem Signature 06
Sig[5].Value=4c2b4e90
Sig[6].Name=Problem Signature 07
Sig[6].Value=17
Sig[7].Name=Problem Signature 08
Sig[7].Value=1
Sig[8].Name=Problem Signature 09
Sig[8].Value=System.IO.FileNotFoundException
DynamicSig[1].Name=OS Version
DynamicSig[1].Value=6.1.7600.2.0.0.256.48
DynamicSig[2].Name=Locale ID
DynamicSig[2].Value=3081
UI[2]=C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\Common7\IDE\devenv.exe
UI[3]=Microsoft Visual Studio has encountered a problem and needs to close.
UI[4]=If you had files open that contained unsaved changes, these changes might be lost.
UI[5]=Check online for a solution and restart the program
UI[6]=Check online for a solution later and close the program
UI[7]=Close the program
Sec[0].Key=LCID
Sec[0].Value=1033
State[0].Key=Transport.DoneStage1
State[0].Value=1
FriendlyEventName=Stopped working
ConsentKey=CLR20r3
AppName=Microsoft Visual Studio
AppPath=C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\Common7\IDE\devenv.exe
```

Any advice appreciated. I've tried emailing Resco yesterday but they haven't replied. I thought they had good support?

Cheers
Mark

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the reason this wasn't working was I didn't have the controls appearing in the toolbox. I'm not sure as I've decided not to bother testing this product and just use the controls. Also Resco advised me that they found an issue running the product under Windows 7 and have updated it yesterday.